# How to write multiple signature hints in PyCharm with Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting

I written a function with an argument on the left, just similar like the built-in `range` function

The problem is, how to write type hints that can show the two way it should be invoked.

For example, when I type Command+p(Ctrl+p) in `range` function in PyCharm(range is an object in py3, but it is not the problem):

```
self:range, stop: int
-------------------------------------------------
self:range, start: int, stop: int, step: int=-1
```

[image: type hints picture of range function]

But for `my_range`:

```
def my_range(start: int, stop: int = None, step: int=1):
"""
list_range(stop) 
list_range(start, stop, step)

return list of integers from start (default 0) to stop,
incrementing by step (default 1).

"""
if stop is None:
    start, stop = 0, start
return list(range(start, stop, step))
```

after type Command + p , I got:

```
start: int, stop: Optional[int], step: int=-1
```

Does anyone knows how to implement that? Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Perhaps try looking into using [overloads](http://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/function_overloading.html)? (Function overloads are a part of PEP 484, which Pycharm understands/is actively working towards conforming towards. The linked docs states that mypy understands the overload annotation only in stubs, but idk if that's up-to-date/if that's also the case for Pycharm). (See [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/3/builtins.pyi#L717) if you want to see the exact type annotations the `range` function/object has).

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module! It's got a lot of helpers to do with type annotations, including `typing.Optional`. Use it like this:

```
import typing

def f(required_arg: int, optional_arg:typing.Optional[int]=None):
    # ...
```